# get php virtual() response headers

Tags: php, reverse-proxy, response-headers

The following makes a sub-request and outputs its body HTTP response content:

```
<?php 
if (condition()) {
    virtual('/vh/test.php');
}
?>
```

***Is there a way to get its response headers?***

My goal is to forward my request (with request headers) to other location on other host, which is accomplished with Apache ProxyPass directive, and set its response (headers and content) as the response to my request.

So my server would act as a reverse proxy. But it will test some condition which requires php context to be done, before forwarding the request.

Comment: If you really insist on doing it with PHP, try CURL: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php

Answer (score 3):

Lets say, that current page has own `original` headers. By using [`virtual()`](http://php.net/virtual) you are forcing apache to perform sub-request, which generates additional `virtual` headers. You might get difference of those two header groups (by saving each with [`apache_response_headers()`](http://php.net/apache-request-headers)) by [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array-diff):

```
<?php
$original   = apache_response_headers();

virtual('somepage.php');

$virtual    = apache_response_headers();
$difference = array_diff($virtual, $original);

print_r($difference);
?>
```

However it will not help you to change current request headers because of [this](http://php.net/virtual):

> To run the sub-request, all buffers are terminated and flushed to the
>   browser, pending headers are sent too.

Which means, that you can not send headers anymore. You should consider usage of [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) instead:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$cUrl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://somewhere/somepage.php");
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($cUrl);
curl_close($cUrl); 

print_r($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTTP Library - https://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php